# eclipse - search variable name by it's value in debugger

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging web app, which produces very complex bean as result of form, and I'd like to know if value that I entered on some form field is present somewhere or not.

Is there any way to find if some of my variables (on debug list) has given value?

PS:

There isn't any way to search thou all variables (I have hundreds of them...) shown in debug  list? Problem is that this bean is made of tens of hashmaps and lists, on different levels. And real problem is that I don't really know which variable holds this value or if it wasn't saved to any variable. And I can't write such big expression cover all of variables, structure is too complex.

Comment: You could use a conditional break point, i.e. break only if the expression is true. The expression might be something like `yourExpectedValue.equals(yourBean.getValue())`. - If you don't know which variable might have that value you could create a bigger expression using or-statements etc. and check all possible variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a breakpoint at a location where you can access the variables you want, then add a watch for each variable and you can see the list of the values of the variables in the watch list

**PS:** In a watch you can write whatever Java code you want such as `x.equals("value")` and it will output **true** if equals or **false** if otherwise. Or you can just visualize the variable's value directly

Comment: I have editted my question. `watch` is not an option. I have hashmaps inside hashmaps inside hashmaps and so on - it's nightmare :)

Comment: @dantuch AFter you edit, your question became unclear to me. sorry

Comment: @dantuch did you ever find a solution for this?  Would be very useful!

Comment: @DanielPatrick no, in fact I changed my work and now I no longer maintain such nightmare, so I stopped searching for a solution. :)